# mithril.js not loading new pages properly?

Tags: mithril.js

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if Mithril is. I have a route, say `/admin/channels/edit/1`. If I were to navigate to `/admin/channels/edit/2` nothing is changed. As each route makes a request to an api no new data is requested from the api. I have the initial request being made in an `oninit` function. Shouldn't the new url force a new request?

Answer (score 1):

Mithril is re-using the component instance since the routes are technically the same.

There's a useful section in the docs for ways to approach this issue: https://mithril.js.org/route.html#key-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess, you could manually call `m.redraw()` in your network call if you didn't use the default `m.request()` function.